# Can't build flutter apk because of File google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a problem when i try to build flutter apk i get this error even tho i have the right file with the right name in the right place !
i tried deleting the pub cash folder from flutter folder but still the same

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:processReleaseGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.1.18\android\src\release\google-services.json
> AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.1.18\android\src\google-services.json
> AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.1.18\android\google-services.json

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           68.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: google-services.json do you have this file in your project. have you added firebase connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was similar to your 'BUILD FAILURE'
Compiler tried to find '`google-services.json`' in '`\flutter\.pub-cache`'

So I solved it by clearing the cache folder. (see below)

---

### Solution

#### Step 1

###### Clear the cache

Clear the global PUB_CACHE:

`flutter pub cache clean`

or

Go to that path and directly delete the cache.

#### Step 2

###### Get packages and run

`flutter pub get`

and

`flutter run`

---

I hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: This was answered on 19th of June by another poster ...

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

**It helped me in my case**

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me before and the reason was that there was a space in the file name
"google-services .json"

So double-check if the file name is exactly like this **"google-services.json"**
and the path for the file is **APP_NAME\android\app\google-services.json**

If everything is correct run **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get**